# A Coin Flip Problem

Tags: probability

Suppose I have $n$ fair coins, and I mark one of them for identification. Next I flip the $n$ coins without looking. My friend, who is looking on, now informs me that there were at least $k$ heads flipped.

What is the probability that my marked coin was heads?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @ Stephan Kolassa, The problem is not from a course or textbook, at least not one I know.

Comment: Do you believe the outcomes of the other $n-1$ coins somehow determine that probability?  If so, please explain how.  Otherwise, you may ignore them, allowing you to restate your question as "A fair coin is flipped: what is the probability it landed heads?"  If you think that's anything but a trivial question, then its content must reside in what you mean by "fair," so please explain your meaning.

Comment: @Whuber, if I am informed that 10 of 10 were heads, then the probability that the marked coin is heads is 1. If I am informed there were no heads, the probability of the marked coin being heads is 0. So, yes, the observation matters. I am interested in the probability conditional on the observation.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that additional information.  In light of it, could your question perhaps be rephrased as "Ten identical (fair) coins have been flipped of which $k$ show heads.  My coin could be any one of these ten coins, with equal probability.  What is the chance it shows heads?"

Comment: its k/n if it is exactly k and not "at least k". If it is "at least k" then it can be (k + 0.5(n-k))/n ,  but I am not sure

Comment: From my calculation the answer is $$\frac{\sum_{i=k}^{n} \binom{n - 1}{i - 1}}{\sum_{i=k}^{n} \binom{n}{i}}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let your coin be $X_1$ and denote sum of heads as $S$.

As I have written in the comment the answers seems to be

$$P(X_1 = 1| S \ge k) = \frac{\sum_{i = k}^{n} \binom{n-1}{i-1}}{\sum_{i=k}^{n}\binom{n}{i}}$$

Here is a plot of theoretical vs sample probabilities with $n = 20$ and 1e^7 trials

[image]

We can see that with low values of $k$ we get almost no additional information, thus the probability is close to unconditional $0.5$

Partially recreated code as requested by @Maximilian

```
library(tidyverse)

coin_flips <- function(n, k) {
    # Create n x k matrix of binary outcomes
    flips <- matrix(as.numeric(rbinom(n * k, 1, 0.5)), ncol = k)
    firsts <- flips[, 1]
    flips <- t(apply(flips, 1, sort, decreasing = T)) # i-th column is an indicator value [S >= i]
                                                      # where S is the sum of heads
    flips <- as.tibble(flips)
    f <- function(x) {
        if (sum(x) > 0) {
            return(sum(x * firsts) / sum(x))
        }
        return(1)
    }
    summary <- flips %>%
        summarise_all(.funs = f)
    colnames(summary) <- 1:k
    return(summary)
}
# Example usage
cf <- coin_flips(1000000, 20)
cf %>% gather %>% ggplot(aes(as.numeric(key), value)) + geom_point() + ylim(c(0.48, 1))
```

Comment: The left asymptote at $0.5$ looks so unreasonable that you should consider elaborating on the assumptions you have made to derive this formula.  In effect, it looks like you are allowing an arbitrary (and unnecessary) prior to dominate the solution when $k$ is small.

Comment: @whuber Hmm, I thought the result is reasonable since for small k the probability of a condition $P(S \ge k)$ is close to 1, thus it brings no new information

Comment: There are at least two ways to interpret the question, "probability my marked coin was heads." After a conversation with the OP in comments to the question, I understand it to ask for the probability *conditional* on observing $k$ heads out of $n$ coins. The exchangeability of the distribution implies the answer is simply $k/n$. Because you are getting values that depart hugely from that number (and it seems they would still be close to $1/2$ even if $n$ were enormous), you must be adopting a very strong prior indeed.

Comment: @whuber In the question OP states the condition is at least $k$ heads out of $n$ flips. If we condition on exactly $k$ heads then of course i agree the probability is $k/n$

Comment: Ahh, I continue to misread this question for some reason.  Thank you for pointing out the "at least."  (In my defense, "at least" is inconsistent with examples given by the OP in comments, all of which refer to *specific* values of the head count--namely, 10 and 0.)  Now your result makes perfect sense.

Comment: The solution by Łukasz Grad is correct, his only "mistake" is using the term "Bayes formula" for something which is clearly not Bayes formula but just plain conditional probability formula (no priors involved in the calculation).

Comment: @whuber Yes, now that I have read it, it is confusing. Maybe OP meant to say exactly $k$ out of $n$, then I have answered a different question. Anyway, I tried to simplify the formula but without success, maybe there is a nice closed form approximate formula, the curve looks something like softplus function

Comment: Re simplification: the numerator and denominator are both Binomial tail probabilities, and therefore can be expressed as incomplete Beta functions.  There is not, in general, any algebraic simplification.

Comment: This is the answer to the posed question regardless of comments to the contrary.

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad; could you pls disclose the `r` code I seems to have troubles to replicate this solutions..thanks.

Comment: @Maximilian Sadly it seems I haven't saved the r code for this one. If you still have some troubles I will try to replicate and post it in my free time

Comment: @Ł yes, if you could redo the solution and post the `r` solution that would be very kind. Many thanks.

Comment: @Maximilian Ok I recreated the sample part

Comment: Nice answer (+1). I would correct "the answers seems to be" to "the answer is" - your result makes perfect sense and it's confirmed by simulation, so you could allow yourself a bit more self-confidence ;-) It would also interesting to add a brief description of how you arrived at this formula - it's easy to guess that you used the Bayes' formula + the CDF of a Binomial variable, but still, it would make the answer more complete, IMO.